# checkbox with new render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to re render a page with a checkbox that has been selected prior to the render.

With the result, I converted it to an integer.

if I have the following code, how do I make the checkbox either checked or not

```
check_box("price", "total", {:checked => @checkVal})  where @checkVal is my checked/not value (int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [check_box](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002408), Rails is assuming that you have a `@price` object that has a `total` attribute. If this is the case, you can set the checkbox to be checked by setting `@price.total` to true (likely in your controller). Example:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.terms_of_service = true
  end
```

will result in a checked box in your view:

```
<%= check_box(:user, :terms_of_service) %>
```

If you don't have a Price model with a total attribute, you likely should be using [check_box_tag](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.5/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002289) instead (which has info on how to set checked).

Answer (score 1):

If the data isn't coming from a table you want to be using check_box_tag:

```
check_box_tag("price", "total", @checkVal)
```